# How to retrieve a stored procedure using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to retrieve a `stored procedure` using c#?

What i need to do is i have to search for a particular stored procedure name in a database and if that stored procedure is available means i have to retrieve that stored procedure and write into a text file..

I dont know how to retrieve stored procedure.

Any Suggestion?

EDIT:i have retrieved the stored procedure names using `SELECT NAME from SYS.PROCEDURES` 
and i dont know how to retrieve those stored procedures

Comment: Which type of database are you using, and which way are you accessing it (ADO.Net EF, Linq-to-SQL classes, SQL driver, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/how-do-i-find-a-stored-procedure-containing-text.html

Then just create the SqlConnection & SqlCommand as normal and execute the SQL to find out the details of the proc:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
    WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = @YourDesiredStoredProc;
    AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
```

C#:

```
// details is a custom class you would use to hold the details of the proc :)
// Boring connection stuff
if(reader.Read())
{
    this.details = new StoredProcedure(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1);
}
else
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Procedure does not exist");
}

// Close boring connection stuff.

this.details.Write("your_file_name");
```

Answer (score 3):

you can just write a procedure

```
select Column1,Column2 from sys.procedures where name='yourProcName'
```

Answer (score 1):

If SQLServer: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345443(v=sql.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345443%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
I guess you can execute that sql statement and write the returning value to your textfile.

Answer (score 1):

Execute your query against `sys.syscomments`. According to [MDSN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186293.aspx) it contains entries for each view, rule, default, trigger, CHECK constraint, DEFAULT constraint, and stored procedure within the database. The text column contains the original SQL definition statements.